# Programmatically scroll ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an activity which consists of a `ListView`. The problem is that the background color of the activity is the same color as the `ListView` (whithin that activity), what causes a lot of users to miss the fact that they are able to scroll the list.

I want to achieve an effect on which when the activity loads, I will programmatically scroll the list for a few milliseconds and scroll back, so the user will understand it is scrollable.

Can it be done? (API 7)

Comment: I'd rethink your logic on that one personally... perhaps an animated drawable that says "Scroll Down" or, something.  It's important to maintain the usability of the Android widgets so people know what does what.  Making a ListView look like it's not isn't helping your UX cause any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of scrolling, what about just always showing the Scrollbars?

In your XML (can't find the docs for this, but it shows up in Eclipse as a Property under "Fade scrollbars"):

```
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
```

Or if you need / want to do it programatically, you can use [setScrollbarFadingEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollbarFadingEnabled%28boolean%29):

```
yourView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
```

I would consider auto scrolling of the app somewhat distracting, but having the scrollbar visible is what users are accustomed to from the web.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the method

[`listView.scrollTo(x, y)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29)

or

[`listView.smoothScrollToPosition(...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29)

or

[`listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(..., ...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#smoothScrollToPositionFromTop%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: using these function does not update the listview content...can you pls let me know how to update the listview content?